# Can anyone find this Menander fragment in the original Greek?

Tags: reference-request, ancient-philosophy

I remember when studying ancient Greek many years ago, I was memorizing Menander monostichoi, and there was one that I now want to make a little postcard of, but can't remember exactly what the original was. The translation, I believe, was "There is no shame in, not knowing, inquiring." (Or maybe it was "learning," not "inquiring.") And the transliterated Greek was something like "Ouk estin aischron agnaountan manthanein." But my Greek is very rusty, so I don't remember if I've got all those forms correct. If anyone can identify the fragment (and, even better, link a source for the Greek), I'd be very grateful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Οὐκ ἔστιν αἰσχρὸν ἀγνοοῦντα μανθάνειν.

One source is *[Menandri Sententiae Comparatio Menandri Et Philistionis](https://archive.org/details/menandri-sententiae-comparatio-menandri-et-philistionis-ed.-siegfried-jaeckel)* (ed. Siegfried Jaeckel) in which Γνῶμαι μονόστιχοι number is 561, in some other collections it is 405.